# How to filter SharePoint list using url parameters- SPO Modern UI

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, modern-pages, connected-web-parts

I'm going through this [site](https://natechamberlain.com/2020/05/09/how-to-filter-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-using-url-parameters/). I have created a new page in SPO and have some URL parameter on the top like so below:

```
<a href="MyPage.aspx?FilterField1=FL&amp;FilterValue1=A">A</a>
```

I have also embedded a list on the page (this is all in Modern UI).

When I click on the link above I was expecting the list to filter based on the parameter. But it doesn't work.

This used to work in SharePoint Classic. Anyone achieved similar with Modern UI list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a hyperlink will not filter the list web part on same page automatically in modern experience.

In the blog link you provided, blog author is redirecting users to the default SharePoint list URL & not the custom page URL.

So, if you want to show the hyperlinks & filter list items, you have to generate the link like below & redirect users to list URL:

```
<a href="https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<siteName>/Lists/<listName>/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=FL&amp;FilterValue1=A">A</a>
```

---

**Additional information**:

If you want to have list web part on same page & filter list items, you can use connected web parts in SharePoint online modern experience.

**Example**: Filtering document library based on selection in another SharePoint list.

[image]

Follow below Microsoft documentation to use connected web parts: [Connect web parts in SharePoint](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/connect-web-parts-in-sharepoint-b457668c-d843-4b1b-8977-a6f9228a1dec)